# data.table select rows by a condition on the other condition

Tags: r, data.table

I have a given datatable

```
A  B
1  2
3  4
3  2
2  1
```

I would like to select the row with the maximum A. If there is more than one row with the maximum A, I will select the row with the maximum B from the selected rows. Here should get

```
A  B
3  4
```

How should I achieve it using `data.table`?

Comment: Try `df[,lapply(.SD,max)][]`

Comment: @NelsonGon - that gives the column maximums independent of each other, not the row maximum for A.

Comment: Thanks for the correction @thelatemail

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Data:

```r
x <- read.table(header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, text = "
A  B
1  2
3  4
3  2
2  1")
```

Working code:

```r
library(data.table)
x[ head(order(A, B, decreasing = TRUE), n = 1), ]
#    A B
# 1: 3 4
```

An alternative:

```r
x[ order(A, B, decreasing = TRUE)[1], ]
```

is valid, but produces a row of `NA` when `nrow(x)==0`, where I would prefer/expect 0 rows. For example:

```r
x[0,][ order(A, B, decreasing = TRUE)[1], ]
#     A  B
# 1: NA NA
x[0,][ head(order(A, B, decreasing = TRUE), n = 1), ]
# Empty data.table (0 rows) of 2 cols: A,B
```

Another alternative, my first suggestion:

```r
x[ order(A, B, decreasing = TRUE), ][1,]
```

It is perfectly legitimate but as @thelatemail suggested (thanks!), it is far less efficient in that it produces the whole (restructured) frame before giving you the first row.

Yet another alternative (from the crowd, thanks again thelatemail):

```r
setorder(x, -A, -B)[1]
```

Comment: `dat[order(A,B,decreasing=TRUE)[1]]` or your second example would probably be better since you're not doing a selection on the whole `x` first just to take one row.

Comment: Rather than polluting with a separate one line answer, would you like to add `setorder(x, -A, -B)` as an option too? It is apparently ordering of data.table by reference.

Comment: In a way, yes, but that side-effect (contrary to all of `data.table`'s other side effects) might not be (as) desirable. That is, in the answer, the table is unchanged so the only "think" being calculated/manipulated is the vector from `order`. In your suggestion, it is reordering all of the vectors within the table. This may not be expensive, but unless you really want it to *stay* in that order, it is unnecessary. (Unless I misunderstand how `data.table` uses `setorder`, which is entirely possible.)

Comment: I think your understanding is correct. It may well not be a desirable outcome!

Comment: To leave the original table unchanged `setorder(copy(x), A, B)[.N]`.

Comment: sindri_baldur, how is that better? It doesn't rearrange the original frame, true, but its double-memory requirement is completely unnecessary (especially for large frames). (It has the same memory requirement of my original first answer, admittedly the least efficient of the answer alternatives.